# Unable to connect to google mysql proxy pod via service name

Tags: kubernetes

**Context:**

I have a java application which connects to Google SQL servers via Google Proxy.

So I have three pod running `google-proxy` on 3306 and k8s service on the top of it say `google-proxy-service`. Apart from this, I have 3 pods of my java application that connects to `google-proxy-service` to execute the select query.

Problem is, my java application is not able to connect to `google-proxy-service`. Logs of java application says

```
MacBook-Pro-3:seeker unbxd$ kubectl logs argo-seeker-job--1-ws7c2 -f
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Seeker.main(Seeker.java:65)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Here is the yaml of `google-proxy` pod

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: google-proxy-deployment
  labels:
    app: google-porxy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: google-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: google-proxy
    spec:
      containers:

        - name: cloud-sql-proxy
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            # It is recommended to use the latest version of the Cloud SQL proxy
          # Make sure to update on a regular schedule!
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
          command:
            - "/cloud_sql_proxy"

              # If connecting from a VPC-native GKE cluster, you can use the
              # following flag to have the proxy connect over private IP
              # - "-ip_address_types=PRIVATE"

              # Replace DB_PORT with the port the proxy should listen on
            # Defaults: MySQL: 3306, Postgres: 5432, SQLServer: 1433
            - "-instances={{ .Values.db_instance_name }}=tcp:{{ .Values.db_port}}"
            - "-credential_file=/tmp/foo/google-cloud-service-account.json"
          securityContext:
            # The default Cloud SQL proxy image runs as the
            # "nonroot" user and group (uid: 65532) by default.
            runAsNonRoot: true
            # Resource configuration depends on an application's requirements. You
            # should adjust the following values based on what your application
            # needs. For details, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

          volumeMounts:
            - name: google-cloud-service-account
              mountPath: "/tmp/foo"

      volumes:

        - name: google-cloud-service-account
          secret:
            secretName: google-proxy-secrets
            items:
              - key: google-cloud-service-account
                path: google-cloud-service-account.json
```

Here is the yaml of `google-proxy-service`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: google-proxy-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: google-proxy
  ports:
    - name: mysql
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

Here is how my java application connects with `google-proxy-service`

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://google-proxy-service:3306/argo","YZX","MAJDHSGA");
```

All pods are in the same namespace and I tried NS looking up `google-proxy-service` I am getting the IP address returned.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: `kubectl get deployment google-proxy-deployment` shows 3/3 pods running?

Comment: Does `telnet google-proxy 3306` work? You can create a separate pod and run this command from it. This why you can rule out kubernetes network and focus on deployment itself or what's going further.

Comment: @gohm'c : yes it shows 3/3 Ready and available 3 .. All good here.